# Unable to start ruby server on c9. io ide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cloud9-ide, c9.io

I am trying  to start  ruby  server  on cloud9 ide.  But I am encountering  this error in the  screenshot.I am using  this command

> rails server -b $IP -p $Port

But after  using  this I am encountering this error  take a look

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeOAN.jpg)

Comment: hi, it's better to paste your error than to include a screenshot. Looking at your error, I think the value of `$Port` is nil. can you run `echo $Port` and see what it outputs?

Comment: Yeah  I've  tried echo  $Port it's  showing  null  value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there something wrong with your $Port variable. Can you try it with a hardcoded port number without using variable? If it would work, in this case $Port variable is not being set correctly.